# major purveyors of viral spread

Tags: word-meaning

Does "major" in the phrase "major purveyors of viral spread" mean:

(1) main; greater or more important (like in ‘he got the major share of the spoils’)

(2) significant, important.

Which?   If (1), then when come to proportions, it is at least bigger than 55%.    If (2), then 30% is still counted as an important propotion.

> 

The United States and many parts of the world have now lost control of the Covid-19 pandemic owing to the respiratory spread of SARS-CoV-2 and to inconsistent adherence to effective public health measures, including wearing masks and maintaining social distancing. Persons infected with SARS-CoV-2 are frequently asymptomatic, yet they have high respiratory viral loads, and they are **major purveyors of viral spread**. These factors have led to the current explosion of Covid-19 hospitalizations and deaths, with Covid-19 now a major cause of death in the United States.

> Source: New England Journal of Medicine    (Editorial)
> [A New Vaccine to Battle Covid-19](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMe2035557)

Comment: I think it has to be your (2). If it was your (1), the phrasing would be "they are **the** major purveyors".

Comment: I agree with @legatrix, they are ***some of** the main purveyors", not ***the** main purveyors*. There's no quantity associated with the word by the way, it's a subjective thing - *main* just means *the most important*, *the most significant*, *the biggest part* etc.